# How to choose and open available navigation app from Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the following code to open Navigation App from one of the button click in my content page.

```
var location = new Location(Convert.ToDouble(jobItem.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(jobItem.Longitude));
var options = new MapLaunchOptions { NavigationMode = NavigationMode.Driving };
await Map.OpenAsync(location, options);
```

There are Google Maps and Waze in my android phone, so the code above did show the selection panel and let user to choose which app to use which is no issue. However, when this meet iOS, it straight away open Apple Maps without any selection even though there are 3 navigation apps in the iPhone. I have tried to research to deal with the default navigation app setting on iOS but unfortunately iOS didn't provide any single option to set the app as default unlike android. What else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[Xamarin.Essentials: Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=android)** NuGet package.

You'd need to modify the code to look something like the below pseudocode

```
var supportsWaze = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync("whateverTheWazeUriSchemeIs://");
var supportsGoogleMaps = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync("whateverTheUriSchemeIs://");
```

You'd then need to give the user some sort of UI for them to select a mapping app based upon these boolean(s) being true. I'd use an **[ActionSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#guide-users-through-tasks)**

Then you can use the `await Launcher.OpenAsync` method to open the correct URI based on whatever choice the user made. You could offer them the option to remember this choice for later as well.

iOS wont allow you to override the OS default apps, but within your own app you can choose how other applications are launched. The Google applications are a good example of this.